# Tinkerpop 3: compute connected components with Gremlin traversal

Tags: gremlin, connected-components, tinkerpop3

I think the tags explain quite well my problem :)

I've been trying to write a Gremlin traversal to compute the connected components of the simple graph described at the end of the post.

I tried with

```
g.V().repeat(both('e')).until(cyclicPath()).dedup().tree().by('name').next()
```

obtaining

```
==>a={b={a={}, c={b={}}, d={c={d={}}}}, c={d={c={}}}}
==>e={f={e={}, g={f={}}}, h={f={h={}}}}
==>g={f={g={}}}
```

which is bad, since the `cyclicPath` filter terminated the traversal starting from `e` before reaching `g`. 
Obviously, if I remove the `until` clause I get an infinite loop.
Moreover, if I use `simplePath` the traverse ends after one step. 
Is there any way to tell it to explore the nodes in depth-first order?

Cheers!

```
a = graph.addVertex(T.id, 1, "name", "a")
b = graph.addVertex(T.id, 2, "name", "b")
c = graph.addVertex(T.id, 3, "name", "c")
d = graph.addVertex(T.id, 4, "name", "d")
e = graph.addVertex(T.id, 5, "name", "e")
f = graph.addVertex(T.id, 6, "name", "f")
g = graph.addVertex(T.id, 7, "name", "g")
h = graph.addVertex(T.id, 8, "name", "h")

a.addEdge("e", b)
a.addEdge("e", c)
b.addEdge("e", c)
b.addEdge("e", d)
c.addEdge("e", d)

e.addEdge("e", f)
e.addEdge("e", h)
f.addEdge("e", h)
f.addEdge("e", g)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query [was also discussed in the Gremlin-users group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gremlin-users/TjFlUPSuhiY). 
Here is the solution I came out with. 
@Daniel Kuppitz also had an interesting solution you can find in the mentioned thread.

I think that if it is always true that in an undirected graph the "last" node of the traversal of a connected component either leads to a previously visited node (`cyclicPath()`) or has degree <=1 this query should work

`g.V().repeat(both('e')).until( cyclicPath().or().both('e').count().is(lte(1)) ).dedup().tree().by('name').next()`

On my example it gives the following output

```
gremlin>  g.V().repeat(both('e')).until(cyclicPath().or().both('e').count().is(lte(1))).dedup().tree().by('name').next()
==>a={b={a={}, c={b={}}, d={c={d={}}}}, c={d={c={}}}}
==>e={f={e={}, g={}, h={f={}}}, h={f={h={}}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to enhance the @Alberto version, which is working well, you can use the `simplePath()` traversal step (http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#simplepath-step) to ensure that the traverser does not repeat its path through the graph

```
g.V().repeat(both().simplePath())
  .until(bothE().count().is(lte(1)))
  .dedup().tree().by('name').next()
```